# build a const char * quickly in c++

Tags: c++

Suppose I have a log function like this:

```cpp
void myLog(const char* msg);
```

**The above function can't be changed.**

How can I call it easily in C++? Usually I write the code like this:

```cpp
stringstream ss; 
ss << "name : " << name << " age " << age;
mylog(ss.str().c_str());
```

Can I can reduce the 3 lines to 1 line in c++ somehow?

Comment: Yes, you can. Just don't hit enter.

Comment: `mylog(std::string(std::string() + "name: " + name + " age " + age).c_str());`

Comment: Side note: I don't know what your motivation is, but you shouldn't think using fewer lines is the sign of a better programmer. Writing clearer lines is the sign of a better programmer. Forcing something into fewer lines is frequently the sign of a more novice programmer. If this is something you do repeatedly, make it a function.

Comment: In C++20, `myLog(std::format("name : {} age {}", name, age).c_str());` will work.

Comment: @OP You should realize that the code you write is very seldom the code that is actually generated by the compiler (if optimizations are turned on).  The code you write is only a description of what you want to do.  The compiler is free to optimize as much as it can, so long as the results are the same.  So judging "quickness" by the number of lines of code is not a valid way of determining efficiency.

Comment: Just define helper function.

Answer (score 10):

If you use C++ 20, you should be able to use `std::format`.

So your code would look like this:

```
myLog(std::format("name: {} age: {}", name, age).c_str());
```

Comment: Note that OP didn't have a colon after 'age'. I don't know if that was intentional or not, but this variant makes it easy to see that.

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can, if you are willing to put some code in a seperate header file :

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

// given
void myLog(const char* msg)
{
    std::cout << msg << "\n";
}

// this goes into a header file
namespace details
{

    // this function is called with a variable number of arguments
    // by splitting the template into a value_t and a variadic part
    // we basically pick out only the first argument 
    template<typename value_t, typename... args_t>
    void stream_to_os(std::stringstream& os, const value_t& value, args_t&&... args)
    {
        // pick out the first argument and stream it to the stringstream
        os << value;

        // then check (at compile time!) if there are any more arguments to stream
        // if so recurse into this function. Rince and repeat.
        if constexpr (sizeof...(args_t) > 0)
        {
            stream_to_os(os, std::forward<args_t>(args)...);
        }
    }
}

// make use of the fact that you can overload existing functions
// if a const char* is passed then still the original log function will be selected
// otherwise this template function is considered.
template<typename... args_t>
void myLog(args_t&&... args)
{
    // create the stream once
    std::stringstream os;

    // then stream the variadic arguments to the stringstream
    details::stream_to_os(os, std::forward<args_t>(args)...);

    // and now call the original myLog function
    myLog(os.str().c_str());
}

//--------------------------------------------------------
// add an include to the header file with the stuff above
// and you can log like this:

int main()
{
    const char* name{ "John Doe" };
    unsigned int age{ 42u };

    myLog("name = ", name, ", age = ", age);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think this is my favourite. This way `myLog` is still clear and also a one-liner. I agree with the fact that is better a clear code than a too compact one, but 3 lines every time you have to log something are clearly 2 lines more than the necessary.

Comment: Best of all:  *no macros!*  (My comment in the other answer suggested a macro.  But I hate macros.)

Comment: @Eljay So do I ;)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can stream into a temporary `std::stringstream`

```
myLog((std::stringstream{} << "name : " << name << " age " << age).str().c_str());
```

[See it on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/926583b9d8d7aa65)

Comment: Upvoted because this answers the question well. But, to the OP: this is less readable and not better than the original code in my opinion. See my comment under the question. Use your original code.

Comment: Update to the OP: eh, I have mixed feelings. This is pretty simple still. Use whatever you want.

Comment: A helper function-like macro: `#define MYLOG(x) myLog((std::stringstream{} << x).str().c_str())`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::to_string` and addition operator instead of the string stream, but that limits you to conversion of built in types (or other types with this function implemented for)

```
mylog(("name:" + name + " age:" + std::to_string(age)).c_str());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a problem with using `printf`-like function in c++, you can use this: (it just forwards your arguments to `sprintf` and returns the result string).

```
const char *mprintf(char *format, ...)
{
    static char buffer[1024];

    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    sprintf(buffer, format, args);

    return buffer;
}
```

(Note that you should not store the return value cause it'll be changed in the next call.)

```
myLog(mprintf("%s %d", name.c_str(), age));
```

But the main answer, You can simply wrap your logic into a function like this

```
template<typename ...Args>
std::string mprintf(Args... args)
{
    std::ostringstream ret;

    ([&ret](const auto &value){
        ret << value;
    }(args), ...);

    return ret.str();
}
```

```
myLog(mprintf("name = ", name, "age = ", age, '\n').c_str());
```

(Note that in this case the `c.str()` cannot be placed `mprintf`!)